# What does osmnx reversed mean in an arc?

Tags: python, optimization, graph, networkx, osmnx

I am working with osmnx for my research paper. I wondered what the reversed attribute in an arc mean since i have identical arcs:

```
        u         v  key    osmid  oneway             name       highway  \
6362  214  45107731    1  7012709   False  Ridderplantsoen  unclassified   
6364  214  45107731    0  7012709   False  Ridderplantsoen  unclassified   

     maxspeed reversed   length  \
6362       30     True  77.9805   
6364       30    False  77.9805   

                                               geometry access lanes bridge  \
6362  LINESTRING (5.12597 52.06862, 5.12592 52.06864...    NaN   NaN    NaN   
6364  LINESTRING (5.12597 52.06862, 5.12605 52.06863...    NaN   NaN    NaN   

     width tunnel  ref est_width junction  
6362   NaN    NaN  NaN       NaN      NaN    
6364   NaN    NaN  NaN       NaN      NaN
```

and the arcs exist vice versa as well.

```
        u         v  key    osmid  oneway             name       highway  \
6001  45107731  214    1  7012709   False  Ridderplantsoen  unclassified   
6002  45107731  214    0  7012709   False  Ridderplantsoen  unclassified   

     maxspeed reversed   length  \
6362       30     True  77.9805   
6364       30    False  77.9805   

                                               geometry access lanes bridge  \
6362  LINESTRING (5.12597 52.06862, 5.12592 52.06864...    NaN   NaN    NaN   
6364  LINESTRING (5.12597 52.06862, 5.12605 52.06863...    NaN   NaN    NaN   

     width tunnel  ref est_width junction  
6362   NaN    NaN  NaN       NaN      NaN    
6364   NaN    NaN  NaN       NaN      NaN
```

I do not really understand what reversed does since oneway is also an indicator that an edge has been splitted into two arcs and now when i want to detect an arc based on u,v,osmid (which should be unique) i get multiple arcs. Who could help me out?

Comment: It has been a while since I worked with any geospatial data, but it might be the case that you have near duplicates for a divided highway, where "good data" would include geometry for both directions of travel if they are not completely adjacent.  You'll have to consult the data source.  Plotting them would also be helpful.  I note that the geometry string for them is slightly different, which is an indicator they are slightly displaced.

Comment: See the explanation here: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/pull/814